# Why is my Ising Gauge Theory calculation showing magnetization?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ising-model, spin-models

I wrote a Mathematica code to test out the 2d Ising Gauge Theory (by computing the exact partition fucntion) on a $3\times 3$ lattice (so that there are ($4\times 3$ spins on the horizontal bonds and $3 \times 4$ spins on the vertical bonds). I put an external magnetic field
\begin{equation}
H_\text{ext} = h\sum_{\text{bonds}} \sigma_3,
\end{equation}
and plotted the magnetization per 'bond'
\begin{equation}
M = \frac{1}{2n(n+1)}\frac{\partial \log Z(\beta,h)}{\partial \beta h}.
\end{equation}
I obtained the following plot
[image]

It seems to me that there is some residual magnetization as $T\to 0$. But this is strange to me as this model does not have a phase transition? Shouldn't this hint towards a phase transition which *does not* happen in the case of the Ising Gauge theory? Another plot which I made was $M$ vs. $T$ for different values of $h$ and I got this. Is this consistent with theory?
[image]

Comment: I might be completely missing the point but: the 1D ising model also have a non-zero magnetization for any temperature as long as there is a magnetic field? See for example: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Magnetisation-vs-external-magnetic-field-h-for-1D-Ising-model-J-1_fig1_324599063  . This does not mean that there is a phase transition (there is no critical behavior at $T_c$ as expected for a continuous transition or a discontinuity of the magnetization at $h = 0^+$ and $h = 0^-$ as expected for a first order phase transition)